# Searching for the name of the gym equipment which allows foot press

Tags: exercise, gym

A gym had a machine which allowed the user to sit on its chair and push the pedals back with his feat, the pedals had variable weights.

this was attached to a very big equipment with many other exercise,

I would like to know the name of the equipment which would offer such exercise so a purchase could be made for local store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are describing might be a leg press. As for being attached to other weightlifting apparatuses, I don't have any idea which one it could be. This particular image though is from a [Powerline Home Gym](http://bodybuilderfitness.com/pro933651.html). From what I can gather from Body-Solid (the company that manufacturers this equipment), there is a [leg press attachment](http://www.bodysolid.com/commercial/Item.cfm?ID=376) that is sold separately from their home gyms.

[image: Powerline P1X Home Gym - Leg Press]

Comment: wrong: "this was attached to a very big equipment with many other exercise" That's not a leg press mate.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are talking about something like one of these?

[image: multigym]

That would be something called a [multigym](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=multigym&pbx=1&oq=multigym&aq=f&aqi=g-s3g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1796l1796l0l2799l1l1l0l0l0l0l119l119l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1e0e72d07edee1f3&biw=1920&bih=965)